# Jquery this.find() not picking anything up?

Tags: javascript, listview

I hope you can help. I am trying to set part of a column to a text area.

```
$('#myListview .list-item').click(function() {
    getId('textarea-Status').value(this.innerHTML);
}
```

I printed out 'this' which shows all of my HTML however I only want to show a specific part:-

Within the HTML that I have printed out to a text area I want to be able to print the row ID called 'data-roid'.

```
<div class = "ui-btn-text listview-row" **data-rowid="123456789"**>
```

So basically my new text are value wuld = '123456789'

```
getId('textarea-sysID').value($(this).find('data-rowid').text()));
sysID = $(this.data-rowid); 
alert(sysID.innerHTML);
getId('textarea-sysID').value(sysID);
getId('textarea-sysID').value = JSON.stringify(sysID);
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get element by [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) and attribute value by using [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data) method.

```
$(this).find('[data-rowid]').data('rowid')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3739958 : glad to help you :)